# Python pandas integer YYYYMMDD to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame that looks like the following:

```
OrdNo  LstInvDt
9      20070620
11     20070830
19     20070719
21     20070719
23     20070719
26     20070911
29     20070918
31      0070816
34     20070925
```

`LstInvDt` of `dtype` `int64`. As you can see, the integers are of the format `YYYYMMDD`, e.g. `20070530` - 30th of May 2007. I have tried a range of approaches, the most obvious being;

`pd.to_datetime(dt['Date'])` and `pd.to_datetime(str(dt['Date']))` with multiple variations on the functions different parameters.

The result has been that the date interpreted as being the time. The date is set to `1970-01-01` - outcome as per above example `1970-01-01 00:00:00.020070530`

I also tried various `.map()` functions found in similar posts.

How do I convert it correctly?

Comment: `to_datetime` accepts a format string so `pd.to_datetime(str(t), format='%Y%m%d')` should work: `In [92]:

t = 20070530
pd.to_datetime(str(t), format='%Y%m%d')
Out[92]:
Timestamp('2007-05-30 00:00:00')`

Comment: To be honest I thought it was `uff-8`, but obviously something is happening that I am not aware of. I will have to look at the sql import part again... Thank you for your help @EdChum. You did answer my question, so I will check your answer as accepted. Looks like I will use most of today trying to find out this one...

Comment: It looks to me like the new line character is not being stripped out but it's a bit confusing where/why you seem to have an index ordinal following it, I'd compare against what is stored in your DB and compare with exporting out to csv

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) accepts a format string:

```
In [92]:

t = 20070530
pd.to_datetime(str(t), format='%Y%m%d')
Out[92]:
Timestamp('2007-05-30 00:00:00')
```

example:

```
In [94]:

t = 20070530
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[t]*10})
df
Out[94]:
       date
0  20070530
1  20070530
2  20070530
3  20070530
4  20070530
5  20070530
6  20070530
7  20070530
8  20070530
9  20070530
In [98]:

df['DateTime'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))
df
Out[98]:
       date   DateTime
0  20070530 2007-05-30
1  20070530 2007-05-30
2  20070530 2007-05-30
3  20070530 2007-05-30
4  20070530 2007-05-30
5  20070530 2007-05-30
6  20070530 2007-05-30
7  20070530 2007-05-30
8  20070530 2007-05-30
9  20070530 2007-05-30
In [99]:

df.dtypes
Out[99]:
date                 int64
DateTime    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

Actually it's quicker to convert the type to string and then convert the entire series to a datetime rather than calling apply on every value:

```
In [102]:

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
df
Out[102]:
       date   DateTime
0  20070530 2007-05-30
1  20070530 2007-05-30
2  20070530 2007-05-30
3  20070530 2007-05-30
4  20070530 2007-05-30
5  20070530 2007-05-30
6  20070530 2007-05-30
7  20070530 2007-05-30
8  20070530 2007-05-30
9  20070530 2007-05-30
```

**timings**

```
In [104]:

%timeit df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))

100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop
In [105]:

%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
1000 loops, best of 3: 396 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cast to strings, [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) can parse

> int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series, DataFrame/dict-like

so directly calling it with the specific `format=` should work.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

One useful parameter is `errors=`. By setting it to `'coerce'`, you can get NaT values for "broken" dates instead of having an error raised.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```