# Converting Integers to Dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I have datasets which have the dates in the format of yyyymmdd. For example, May 5th, 2018 would be 20180505.

How can I reformat these entries such that they will be a time series in pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer (YYYYMMDD) to date format (mm/dd/yyyy) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133605/convert-integer-yyyymmdd-to-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert integer into date object python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750330/how-to-convert-integer-into-date-object-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '20180505'
date = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

From this link: [Convert integer (YYYYMMDD) to date format (mm/dd/yyyy) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133605/convert-integer-yyyymmdd-to-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could find everything on pandas docs. Read about [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) in pandas,

```
## sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['20180505','20180506','20180507','20180508']})

## convert to dates
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want also to change the format and this is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['20180505','20180506','20180507','20180508']})
print df
      dates
0  20180505
1  20180506
2  20180507
3  20180508
df['dates'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
print df
```

Output:

```
         dates
0  05/May/2018
1  06/May/2018
2  07/May/2018
3  08/May/2018
```