# Python Convert YYYYMMDD string to YYYY-MM-DD string Without Using Datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime

How can I convert a string such as:

```
'20190501'
```

To a string such as:

```
'2019-05-01'
```

Without first converting to datetime, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('20190501', '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

The above code works, however since I'm starting and ending with a string, it seems unnecessary to use `datetime` in the process. Can I convert the string directly?

Comment: if you don't want to use the `datetime` for whatever reason; you would have to a) make sure that the input is always valid b) then can simply do string manipulation like `'{}-{}-{}'.format(input_date[0:4], input_date[4:6], input_date[6:8])` assuming `input_date` is a valid input date string.

Comment: What's wrong with converting to datetime? It gives you extra data validation for free.

Comment: It's just an extra module to import so was wondering if there was a simpler solution. However good point about data validation.

Comment: The standard way to do this is with the `datetime` module, which is part of the standard library. See [Convert integer (YYYYMMDD) to date format (mm/dd/yyyy) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43133605/7758804) and [How to convert integer into date object python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9750330/7758804)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the format is always YYYYMMDD it can be converted by getting the terms in the following way:

```
s="YYYYMMDD"
s=s[:4]+"-"+ s[4:6]+"-"+s[6:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can slice and format

```
>>> date = '20190501'
>>> newdate = "{}-{}-{}".format(date[:4],date[4:6],date[6:])
>>> newdate
'2019-05-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format is fixed, it's trivial to do with string slicing.

```
d = '20190501'
print(d[0:4] + '-' + d[4:6] + '-' + d[6:8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
before = '20190501'
print('before:', before)
after = ''.join((before[:4],'-',before[4:6],'-',before[6:]))
print('after:', after)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string indexing as follows.

```
old_date = '20200505'

new_date = old_date[:4]+'-'+old_date[4:6]+'-'+old_date[6:8]

print(new_date)
```

2020-05-05