# How can I convert a series of integers into dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series of integers such as

```
151215
```

I want to convert these integers in dates

```
2015-12-15
```

That means 15th December 2015. A quick search on pandas websites suggests me to use the to_datetime() method. Unfortunately I realised that if the the pandas data is a string

```
st = '151215'
pd.to_datetime(st)
```

then it works correctly (except the fact that I don't need the time)

```
Timestamp('2015-12-15 00:00:00')
```

but when pandas data are integers

```
st = 151215
pd.to_datetime(st)
```

the result is

```
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000151215')
```

Could you suggest me an efficient way to convert a list of integers into dates

Comment: `Timestamp` will always store the time. For integers just convert them to strings.

Comment: I suppose you have to convert to a string first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506367/python-pandas-integer-yyyymmdd-to-datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [pandas.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) no need to convert to string first (at least in pandas 0.19):

```
dates = pd.Series([151215]*8)
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates, format="%y%m%d")
print(dates)
0   2015-12-15
1   2015-12-15
2   2015-12-15
3   2015-12-15
4   2015-12-15
5   2015-12-15
6   2015-12-15
7   2015-12-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Converting a single value as in your example will result in `Timestamp('2015-12-15 00:00:00')`, but if you pass the entire series the result looks like the above.

Comment: That's good, but I tryed to add the boolean variable "inplace = True", as it is typically done on pandas dataframe, and it doesn't work. Could you provide me a little further help, please?

Comment: I would point out that you must specify the format.. it would seem the default format for integers is nanoseconds since epoch

Comment: @StefanoFedele I think modifying inplace is frowned upon in general, and there is no `inplace` kwarg for to_datetime as it returns the converted series or value only, not an entire frame. For example if dates was a column in a dataframe you would just say df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, ...) without the inplace kwarg and it would accomplish what you want.

Comment: @StefanoFedele I'm not sure any inplace modifiers can change the data type in pandas..

Comment: @StefanoFedele it is not true that inplace is typically done.

Comment: I deleted that column with the .drop method and "inplace=True" as argument and I concatenated the dataframe with the new series of dates using the .concat method and "axis=1" and "inplace=True" as argument.