# Seaborn and/or Matplotlib is grouping my X axis. How do I stop it being grouped

Tags: pandas, seaborn

My pandas dataframe 'daily_PL_withDate_df' is

[image]

plot code is

```
with sns.axes_style('whitegrid'):
    g = sns.relplot(x='Day', y='PL', data=daily_PL_withDate_df, height=15, aspect=1.5)
```

[image: The resulting plot.]

1. Day column is days in YYYYMMDD format but expressed as a float so as far as I am concerned it's just like any other number being presented to Seaborn and Matplotlib. It is in ascending sequence.
2. It seems to be grouping the data into quarter percentiles and hence the whole of 2017 is in 201700. 2018 and 2019 have the same thing happening.

There's a lot of info about how to group data but I cannot find anything about how to stop this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notIntoXS,

The plot acts normally - it is not grouping the data, rather you see result of your choice of date storage format. The white space between the years on your chart is the gap between integers 20171230 and 20180101 which is much wider than gap between integers 20170101 and 20171231 where your 2017 data sits.

I suggest you to convert the integers into either dates or serial numbers of day - the gaps will go away.

Check out this solution for conversion: [Python pandas integer YYYYMMDD to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506367/python-pandas-integer-yyyymmdd-to-datetime)

Comment: Ah... of course! Thank you @Ruslan S. The X values are not evenly spaced numerically. My brain was in date mode! Another pair of eye is ever so useful. I wish I had 6 of them attached to 1 brain per pair ha ha ha :)