# Pandas.to_datetime misreads years as nanoseconds since 1970

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have yearly data (starting at 2014) saved in an excel file (where the column format is simply Number, not Date). I'm trying to read this into Pandas and convert it to a datetime, such as the first day of the year, using `pd.to_datetime` - but invariably, it interprets the number as the number of nanoseconds after 1970:

```
>> pd.to_datetime(np.array([2014, 2015, 2016]))
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002016'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I'm also doing this in a loop of hundreds different excel sheets of different data frequencies - weekly, monthly, quarterly, and annual. What is the easiest way for me to force pandas to interpret the year as a year and not as a nanosecond? Having to specify a formatting string is impractical because of the large number of sheets - I would have to manually specify them all... Alternatively, is there an easy way to save the date in Excel? There, converting 2014 to a date gets interpreted as the number of days after 1900, which is also bad.

I've tried to search around and I haven't found any question that addresses this exact issue.

Comment: You passed it an `int` so it interprets that as nanoseconds from the POSIX origin by default. If you have a non-unit value, then you need to specify the format: `pd.to_datetime(np.array([2014, 2015, 2016]), format='%Y')`

Comment: It's also unclear why you'd need to specify the formats manually every time. Are you really expecting the data to be so inconsistently formatted? If so you _could_ change the ints to `str`, so that pandas defaults to inferring the format: `pd.to_datetime(np.array([2014, 2015, 2016]).astype(str))` But this is super unsafe and error prone because you're going to blindly confuse days with months based on what pandas thought it should be in cases like 2015-02-03

Comment: Related (dupe?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/27506367/10197418